# How to add random variables in Tensorflow Probability

Tags: tensorflow-probability

Given N independent binomial variables (not identically distributed), how does one compute the probability distribution of the sum of those random variables, in the form of a TensorFlow Probability Distribution object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolution is not analytic in-general. For binomial, if the `p` parameter is the same and only the counts differ, you can [sum the counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions#Discrete_distributions).

If all you want to do is sample, you can write `tf.reduce_sum(tfd.Binomial(total_count=[1, 2, 3], probs=[.2, .3, .4]).sample())`.

Computing `log_prob(x)` would require evaluating all legal allocations of `x` across all the underlying distributions, or using MCMC, ABC, or other schemes.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. The sampling approach you describe in your second paragraph can be used to generate an approximate probability distribution over a finite discrete support. Is it possible to use that list of probability values to create a TensorFlow Probability Distribution object that can be fed to TFP models? For example, assigning the Distribution object to the `observation_distribution` argument of `tfp.distributions.HiddenMarkovModel` or the `observation_fn` argument of `tfp.experimental.mcmc.infer_trajectories` ?

Comment: Also, Brian, less important at this point, but it wasn't obvious to me: how would you use MCMC or ABC to estimate the probability distribution of the sum of random variables?

Comment: There is a `FiniteDiscrete` distribution you might use if you can enumerate exhaustively.

Comment: For MCMC, I mean something (terrible) like this https://colab.research.google.com/gist/brianwa84/c0ad8dfc2f964175cc98fed515874d47/binomialconv.ipynb

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.